# `sort_values` with `key` not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas

```py
names = ['2', '0', '1']
values = [2, 0, 1]
dc = dict(names=names, values=values)
df = pd.DataFrame(dc, columns=list(dc))

key_fn = lambda s: pd.Series(sorted(s, key=lambda name: int(name)))
print(df.sort_values(['names'], key=key_fn))
```

yields

```
  names  values
0     2       2
1     0       0
2     1       1
```

Yet, the sorting is correct, which we can confirm via

```py
kfn = lambda s: print(key_fn(s)) or key_fn(s)
df.sort_values(['names'], key=kfn)
```

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
dtype: object
```

`key_fn` agrees with docs

> *key* function should be *vectorized*. It should expect a Series and return a Series with the same shape as the input.

Why doesn't it work? I'm not looking for a workaround to this simple example, I need to be able to use the general `key`. Windows 10, pandas 1.3.3, Python 3.8.12.

Comment: The `key` argument is used to specify the Series of values that _get sorted_ instead of the actual values in the column. You've instead provided an already sorted collection of values.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. `key` is just some function that manipulates the values so that those _derived_ values are used for sorting, not the original values. I.e. if you want to sort based on the absolute value you would `key = lambda s: s.abs()`. This basically just saves you from creating an intermediate column, sorting on that then dropping that intermediate.

Comment: @HenryEcker The docs are ambiguous in this regard, but you've answered my question. I have the working code but feel free to post the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your key function is already sorted, so there's nothing (left) to sort. Try:

```
key_fn = lambda s: s.astype('int')
```

or:

```
key_fn = lambda s: pd.Series([int(x) for x in s])
```

Comment: As specified, I seek to use the general `key`. This fails if `names = ['r0', 'r1', 'r2']` and doesn't explain why my code doesn't work.

Comment: That's totally different question. Those keys fails on `int(name)` which you didn't ask in this question. So even `sorted(s, key=lambda name: int(name)` is not working. And that's unrelated to the `key` argument in `Pandas.DataFrame.sort_values()`.